# Get value from javascript dict in odoo template's script tag

Tags: javascript, html, xml, odoo

I need to get the value of `elt.innerHTML` and pass it to `fromPage[j].textContent`.

Function borrowed from [GitHub](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/10.0/report_qweb_element_page_visibility).

Currently `vars['hiddenNumber']` is returning `undefined`.

`elt.style.visibility = "hidden";` works as intended tho.

I believe this might be related with variable scopes, but can't seem to find a way to create a global variable. Tried to update `window.value`, but got an error that window is not defined.

Using odoo 13, wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5.

```html
<script>
    function subst() {
        var vars = {};
        var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&amp;');
        for (var i in x) {
            var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
            vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
        }
        var index = vars['webpage'].split('.', 4)[3]

         var operations = {
                    // other operations
             'hidden_page_number': function (elt) {
                 elt.style.visibility = "hidden";
                 vars['hiddenNumber'] = elt.innerHTML;  // This value
             },
         };

         for (var klass in operations) {
             var y = document.getElementsByClassName(klass);
             for (var j=0; j&lt;y.length; ++j)
             operations[klass](y[j]);
         }

         var fromPage = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
         for(var j = 0; j&lt;fromPage.length; j++)
         fromPage[j].textContent = vars['hiddenNumber'];  // Required here

         var toPage = document.getElementsByClassName('topage');
         for(var j = 0; j&lt;toPage.length; j++)
         toPage[j].textContent = vars.sitepages;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a suggestion: you define `vars` outside the closure and then define closure where try to update `vars` but I suppose that inside the closure it creates new scope for `vars` and that's why `vars` is not updated outside

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).